# BINANCE API - Получить баланс -> ошибка HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: delphi, api, rest, indy

Есть API к торговому терминалу: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

На его основание хочу узнать свой текущий баланс, использую ниже приведенный код:

```
function TBinanceApi.GetBalances(var aBalances: TBalances): boolean;
var
    url, sign, queryString, nonce   : string;
    ST                              : SystemTime;
    DT                              : TDateTime;
    uTime                           : int64;
    isGetBalance                    : Boolean;
    idHTTP10                        : TidHTTP;
    responeJsonMemory               : TStringStream;
begin
   isGetBalance := false;

   if (FApiKey  = EmptyStr) or ( FSecretKey = EmptyStr) then
     Exit(False);

   responeJsonMemory := TStringStream.Create;
   idHTTP10 := TidHTTP.Create(nil);

   try
      GetSystemTime(ST);
      DT := EncodeDate(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) + EncodeTime(ST.wHour,
      ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond, ST.wMilliseconds);
      uTime := MilliSecondsBetween(DT, UnixDateDelta);
      nonce := inttostr(uTime);

      url := 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?';
      queryString :='timestamp=' + nonce;
      sign := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(queryString, FApiKey, SHA256);

      idHTTP10.HandleRedirects := True;
      idHTTP10.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-MBX-APIKEY:' + FApiKey);

      url := url + queryString + '&signature=' + sign;

      try
         idHTTP10.Get(url, responeJsonMemory);
      except
         on E: Exception do
            raise Exception.Create('Error Message: ' + E.Message);
      end;

    finally
       idHTTP10.DisposeOf;
       responeJsonMemory.DisposeOf;
       Result := isGetBalance;
    end;

end;
```

При вызове данной функции получаю ошибку: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо сделать 2 вещи: в опциях включить `hoWantProtocolErrorContent`, чтобы получить тело ответа сервера с сообщением об ошибке; подключить IOHandler для работы по https - `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.

Comment: zed - Вы абсолютно правы, добавил все что Вы сказали, теперь уже получаю JSON ответ от сервера с ошибкой: {"code:"-1022,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."}   По ходу не правильно формирую цифровую подпись.... :-( Разбираюсь....

Comment: Нашел ошибку, в подписи указывал API ключ вместо SECRET. Снизу приведу рабочий вариант! zed - Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Если исправление в том что вы опечатались, то вопрос стоит удалить. Иначе, запостите как ответ, а не уточнением в вопросе

Comment: Нет, вопрос был задан корректно. Как указал колега zed у меня не было подключено в опциях hoWantProtocolErrorContent и не использовался TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL. Так же была ошибка в цифровой подписи. Снизу привел рабочий вариант. Надеюсь поможет тем, кто ищет ответ, как правильно составлять запросы к указанному торговому терминалу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привожу рабочий вариант, получение баланса с торгового терминала Binance, используя API https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

```
function TFormMain.GetBalances(): boolean;
var
    url, sign, queryString, nonce   : string;
    ST                              : SystemTime;
    DT                              : TDateTime;
    uTime                           : int64;
    isGetBalance                    : Boolean;
    responeJsonMemory               : TStringStream;
    idHTTP10                        : TidHTTP;
    idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL     : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    jsonText                        : string;
begin
    isGetBalance := false;

    FApiKey             := '***********';
    FSecretKey          := '**********';

    responeJsonMemory := TStringStream.Create;
    idHTTP10 := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
    idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();

    try
        GetSystemTime(ST);
        DT := EncodeDate(ST.wYear, ST.wMonth, ST.wDay) + EncodeTime(ST.wHour, ST.wMinute, ST.wSecond, ST.wMilliseconds);
        uTime := MilliSecondsBetween(DT, UnixDateDelta);
        nonce := inttostr(uTime);

        url := 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?';
        queryString := 'timestamp=' + nonce;
        sign := THashSHA2.GetHMAC(RawByteString(queryString), FSecretKey, SHA256);

        idHTTP10.HandleRedirects := True;
        idHTTP10.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-MBX-APIKEY:' + FApiKey);
        idHTTP10.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
        idHTTP10.IOHandler := idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

        url := url + queryString + '&signature=' + sign;

        try
            idHTTP10.Get(url, responeJsonMemory);
            responeJsonMemory.Position := 0;
            jsonText := responeJsonMemory.DataString;

            OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar('URL: ' + url));
            OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar(jsonText));

            isGetBalance := True;
        except
            on E: Exception do
                raise Exception.Create('Error Message: ' + E.Message);
        end;

    finally
        idSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.DisposeOf;
        idHTTP10.DisposeOf;
        responeJsonMemory.DisposeOf;
        Result := isGetBalance;
    end;

end;
```